# Retain states for the last X blocks in geth

Tags: state, trace

I have a use case where I need to keep states for last 2000 blocks. The default number is 128 if I’m not mistaken.

I’m looking for an option to select minimum number of recent blocks to keep the entire world state for?

In besu, you can specify this with the option --pruning-blocks-retained=. I need an option like this but for geth. I searched everywhere, and I couldn't find it. Is it available?

I have a specific use case, and I don't want to manage archive nodes.

Thanks you.